# When I using libgit2 to push a repo, how can i get the username or password from.git-credentials files?

Tags: libgit2

I am trying to use `libgit2` to push to a repository. I would expect
`libgit2` to provide some way to get the credentials from my `.git-credentials` file, but I can not see any way to do this.

sample code:

```
git_push_options opts = GIT_PUSH_OPTIONS_INIT;

// how can I get username or password from.git-credentials 
opts.callbacks.credentials = cred_acquire_cb;    
error = git_remote_push(remote, &strarr, &opts);
```

Comment: What does your `cred_acquire_cb` _look like_?  Is it reading this file?  Is it returning the values from the callback?  What problems are you having with your code?

Comment: The focus is not cred_acquire_cb, i just would to know how to use Git to get username or password from .git-credentials fie,if you tell me the method,i will be thanks very much!

Comment: libgit2 does not do this for you.  If you want to use a `.git-credentials` file, then you need to open the file, read the values, and then return them from your credential callback.